# Contar frequência de ocorrências incluindo zeros

Tags: r

Para o seguinte caso a contagem de x utilizando a função *table* irá retornar a frequência dos valores existentes. Gostaria de saber como retornar a contagem para o intervalo discreto de 1 a 12, incluindo os valores cuja frequência é zero.

```
set.seed(2)
x <- sample.int(12, 50, replace = TRUE)
table(x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para incluir os valores para os quais a frequência é zero, converta para `factor` com todos os níveis e aplique `table`.

```
table(factor(x, levels = 1:12))
#
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
# 6  6  5  3  3  8  5  5  5  0  2  2
```

O valor 10 tem uma frequência de zero mas está no resultado final, como pedido.

Comment: Esta solução atende o problema. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

`table` usa a função `tabulate`, que retorna por padrão todos os intervalos. Pode usá-la diretamente:

```
set.seed(2)
x <- sample(12, 20, replace = TRUE)

table(x)
#> x
#>  1  2  3  5  6  7  9 10 11 12
#>  1  1  5  1  2  3  1  1  2  3

tabulate(x)
#>  [1] 1 1 5 0 1 2 3 0 1 1 2 3
```

Se precisa que retorne como um vetor nomeado:

```
setNames(tabulate(x), seq_len(max(x)))
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
#>  1  1  5  0  1  2  3  0  1  1  2  3
```